# How to assign an event of a reinitialized element

Tags: c#, events

Hi sorry for the english,
I work on a project where there is an element that is reinitialized of continue but I must assign it an event.

```
Rectangle cell = new Rectangle();
cell.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(cell_MouseLeftButtonDown);
```

I have tried of create an event in this mode but not happend nothing because this part of program is inside of a for cycle and I think that the reinitialized deletes the event.

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: You could make the event `static` and then just subscribe to `Rectangle.MouseLeftButtonDown`.

Comment: Sorry but I am not a senior in C#. You can do an example?

Comment: Show your code for the event and I'll show you how to change it. Include the code for the eventargs type that your `MouseButtonEventHandler` is using.

Comment: I must do an event that when I click on a Rectangle on a Synoptic, appear a tooltip where show some values

Comment: The problem is that this rectangles are always reinitialized because they must represent the objects that flow on the screen

Comment: I can't help you if you won't show your code. I already told you how you can fix it with a static event if you want to try it on your own. Maybe google: c# static event